# How to get list of documents from Raven db

Tags: c#, ravendb

Is there a way to get list of all documents from Raven db as array of Ids or List of Ids.
Type of documents is unknown so it must be handled as dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just read, it is written "all documents" all that exits, I don't know keys.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have millions of documents in a RavenDB database.  Why would you want them in a single array?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
var keys = store.DatabaseCommands.GetDocuments(0, 1024, metadataOnly: true)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToArray();
```

This returns the first 1024 document keys (IDs) from the database.  If you want more, then you'll have to do this in a loop and update the starting index and page size.

I'm not sure why you would want to do this though.  It's very common to have thousands or millions of documents in a database.  You might want to re-think why you need this.  It's not a common thing to do.

Comment: Default editor for raven is really slow and i need to get list of documents so i can create basic version of editor.